# PHPMailer: How do i preserve links in the plain text version?

Tags: phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send a short HTML message that contains two links (and I need to add a third). Using the syntax:

```
$mail ->MsgHTML($htmlmsg);
```

I get a plain text version all right, but the links are no longer there. (just the link text).
By using the 'Body' and 'AltBody' syntax

```
$mail->Body = $htmlmsg;
$mail->AltBody = $textstr;  //  This is the plain text version
```

I have managed to preserve the links by creating my own plain text version ($textstr).  I do it with a bit of 'preg_replace' on the links  (effectively removing the  tags and the "href='...', but leaving the URL), BEFORE applying 'strip_tags'. But I have to devise a specific regex for each link, which is tiresome and error-prone.

Is there a better way? (By which I mean an 'approved by PHPMailer' way). It must be a common requirement.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer generally doesn't care. There is a *very* basic [built-in html to text converter](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L3792) that's used by `msgHTML`. If you want better results, you should [inject your own converter](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L3702), which you can derive from an existing converter such as [html2text](https://packagist.org/packages/html2text/html2text) - this is exactly why such libraries, and the ability to inject a converter, exists.

One of the best ways (the only one I've found that even attempts to preserve layout) is to use a text-based web browser (like lynx or elinks) to render the HTML to text for you, then use that. It's slower and more complicated to set up, but produces much better results than any search & replace approach will.

Comment: Effectively I've already added my own converter, it's just rather tedious (to get right). I'll investigate your other suggestions.